# Should aggregated data include meta data?

Tags: aggregate, big-data

I want to create a aggregation job that executes a big db query and flush it into `BigQuery`.
My question is should I include only the id of the entities (campaign id, advertiser id, user id) or should I include also the meta data (campaign name, advertiser name, user name).

The upside for metadata storing is that I have the whole data in one place.
The downside is that when the metadata been changed (campaign name modified for example) then the whole data should be aggregated again.

Is there a best practice for this kind of situation?

Comment: Could you have regularly scheduled updates to BigQuery?

Comment: yes, everyday new data will be inserted

Comment: You may also need an update process to handle metadata that has changed.